# I changed base url to an address, then changed it back but it keeps jumping to the one I changed!

Tags: base-url, troubleshooting

Sorry if this sounds confusing this is what happened:

I was working on a Magento version on this server, and thought the guy was going to transfer the domain name to point back here. So I went to configuration and changed the base url and the base secure url to the new domain.

I found out the domain isn't ready until Monday! So I went to myPHPadmin and went into core_config_data and changed the url back to the old one so I can continue working on it

Problem is now the site keeps forwarding to the new domain! I checked my core config data and its pointing to my old domain... I even did a database restore and same problem!

What file am I missing to edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the database and can see the Base URL changes in the database, you have one more step.

Magento configuration values are cached. The config cache must be cleared for them to change in running code. In this case, as the Base URL settings don't resolve to to the server that Magento is running on, you need to do a manual clear cache.

Use your sftp client to delete all the `mage--?` subdirectories in `var/cache/`

Answer (score 0):

Try two things

1. Inside **System->Cache Management->Clear all caches.**
2. Inside **System->Configuration->Web->Check Base URL for both Secure & Unsecure.**